# Amazon Web Service Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to fetch collection of items by `ItemSearch` method of Amazon Web Services.

```
ItemSearchResponse response = aws.ItemSearch(itemSearch);
```

But I am facing Bad request issue:

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution using JS:

I got hint to consume amazon service ItemSearch from below link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ReturningPriceAndAvailabilityInformation-itemsearch.html

Got help to create signature & Timestamp parameter from below link:

[How to properly sign a GET request to Amazon's ItemLookup using client-side JavaScript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587599/how-to-properly-sign-a-get-request-to-amazons-itemlookup-using-client-side-java)

Thanks to all of you :-)