# Amazon Signature Creation

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

I am trying to implement itemLookup inside of my app from Amazon's API. I've seen documentation for earlier versions of Swift, but they don't seem to work anymore, but I have it working to a point.

I ported the code from Javascript as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587599/how-to-properly-sign-a-get-request-to-amazons-itemlookup-using-client-side-java)

This is what I have so far:

```
 func callAmazon(){

        let amazonAccessID = "XXXXXX"
        let secretKey = "XXXXXXXXX"
        let associateTag = "XXXXX"

        var parameters = [String]();

        let timestamp = ISO8601FormatStringFromDate(NSDate())

        parameters.append("AWSAccessKeyId=" + amazonAccessID);
        parameters.append("Keywords=" + "boots");
        parameters.append("Operation=ItemSearch");
        parameters.append("Service=AWSECommerceService");
        parameters.append("Timestamp=" + (timestamp as String));
        parameters.append("Version=2013-08-01");
        parameters.append("AssociateTag=" + associateTag);

        parameters.sortInPlace {$0 < $1}
        let paramString = parameters.joinWithSeparator("&")

        let method = NSMutableURLRequest().HTTPMethod

        let signingKey = "\(method)\n" + "webservices.amazon.com\n" + "/onca/xml\n" + paramString

        let signature = sha256(signingKey, secretKey: secretKey)

        let finalString = signature.encodeURIComponent()

        let amazonUrl =  "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?" + paramString + "&Signature=" + finalString!

        print("AmazonURL!!! : ", amazonUrl)


    Alamofire.request(.GET, amazonUrl, parameters: nil).response {
        (request, response, data, error) in
            let xml = SHXMLParser().parseData(data!)
            print(xml)// output the FilmID element.
    }


}

func sha256(StringToSign : String, secretKey : String) -> String{

    var hex = StringToSign.hmac(.SHA256, key: secretKey)
    let hexData = hex.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let finalString = hexData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    return finalString!

}
```

And this is the output.

```
 [ItemSearchErrorResponse: {
Error =     {
    Code = SignatureDoesNotMatch;
    Message = "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.";
};
RequestId = "3d560ce4-a862-4792-953d-c0119cd0478b";
xmlns = "http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-08-01/";
 }]
```

So there is obviously something wrong with how I am creating my signature, can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Hello jared, please post the correct answer because i am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Here is the solution for this problem
[amazon-signature-creation-solution-in-swift-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400364/amazon-signature-creation-solution-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Amazon Signature Creation**

**Here is the soloution of signature creation for aws.**

here is the solution for the AWS signature creation problem in swift.
i have created the AWS request params. and encoded it with HMAC algo.

call the callAmazon method by passing the product id and in response u will receive the xml response which you have to parse.
try out this example: -

```
static func callAmazon(asinId: String){
    // provide your AmazonAccessID, SecretKey and AssociateTag
    let amazonAccessID = "xxxxxxx"
    let secretKey = "xxxxxxx"
    let associateTag = "xxxxx"

    var parameters = [String]();

    let timestamp = Date().iso8601.encodeURIComponent()!

    parameters.append("AWSAccessKeyId=" + amazonAccessID)
    parameters.append("Operation=ItemLookup")
    parameters.append("Service=AWSECommerceService")
    parameters.append("Timestamp=" + (timestamp as String))
    parameters.append("AssociateTag=" + associateTag)
    parameters.append("ResponseGroup="+"Offers")
    parameters.append("ItemId="+asinId)
    parameters.append("IdType=ASIN")

    parameters.sort {$0 < $1}
    let paramString = parameters.joined(separator: "&")

    let method = NSMutableURLRequest().httpMethod

    let signingKey = "\(method)\n" + "webservices.amazon.com\n" + "/onca/xml\n" + paramString

    let signature = signingKey.hmac(algorithm: .SHA256, key: secretKey)

    let finalString = signature.encodeURIComponent()

    let amazonUrl =  "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?" + paramString + "&Signature=" + finalString!

    print("AmazonURL!!! :", amazonUrl)


    AppNetworking.serviceRequestPrice(endPoint: amazonUrl, success: { (data) in

        if let data = data{

            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "CANNOT CONVERT")
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

    }

extension HMACAlgorithm{

func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
    var result: Int = 0
    switch self {

    case .MD5:
        result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
    case .SHA1:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
    case .SHA224:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
    case .SHA256:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
    case .SHA384:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
    case .SHA512:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
    }
    return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
}

func digest_Length() -> Int {

    var result: CInt = 0
    switch self {
    case .MD5:
        result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA1:
        result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA224:
        result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA256:
        result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA384:
        result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA512:
        result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
    }
    return Int(result)
}}

extension String {
// returning encoded signature
func hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
    let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digest_Length()))
    CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, Int(strlen(cKey!)), cData!, Int(strlen(cData!)), &result)
    let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))

    let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedData(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)

   return String(data: hmacBase64, encoding:  String.Encoding.utf8)!
} }

extension String {
// returning encoded url string
func encodeURIComponent() -> String? {
    let characterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumeric()
    characterSet.addCharacters(in: "-_.!~*'()")

    return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characterSet as CharacterSet)
}}

extension Formatter {
// returning iso dateformater
static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    //"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"//"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
    return formatter
}() }

extension Date {
// returning iso date
var iso8601: String {
    return Formatter.iso8601.string(from: self)
}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually solved this months ago, but accepting to help others. :)

Comment: In  swift 3 if give "reponsegroup" = "images,offers" then it says signature does not match. if gave "responsegroup" = "images" then i am getting data from amazon. how should give parameter value for ios swift 3. can you check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868971/how-to-do-product-search-api-in-ios-swift @JaredDavidson

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can see is that your header is not ended by `\n`.

Comment: Fixed - (timestamp as String) + "\n"

Comment: No, that wasn't the fix, I actually figured it out all on my own, took me all week. Either way, I'll give you the bounty because you tried to help. :)

Comment: @JaredDavidson Then post the answer to help viewers of this question.

Comment: @JaredDavidson please post your answer