# How to do product search api in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, swift3

I am using amazon product advertising api for search product. Installed awscore and alamofire cocopods. Done functionality for getting signature and added parameters for item search to get product images, title and description in table view list.

Here is the code i tried for getting amazon search:

```
     private func signedParametersForParameters(parameters: [String: String]) -> [String: String] {
    let sortedKeys = Array(parameters.keys).sorted(by: <)

    let query = sortedKeys.map { String(format: "%@=%@", $0, parameters[$0] ?? "") }.joined(separator: "&")

    let stringToSign = "GET\nwebservices.amazon.in\n/onca/xml\n\(query)"
    print("stringToSign::::\(stringToSign)")

    let dataToSign = stringToSign.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let signature = AWSSignatureSignerUtility.hmacSign(dataToSign, withKey: CameraViewController.kAmazonAccessSecretKey, usingAlgorithm: UInt32(kCCHmacAlgSHA256))!

    var signedParams = parameters;
    signedParams["Signature"] = urlEncode(signature)
    print("urlencodesignature::\(urlEncode(signature))")

    return signedParams
}

public func urlEncode(_ input: String) -> String {
    let allowedCharacterSet = (CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] ").inverted)

    if let escapedString = input.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) {
        return escapedString
    }

    return ""
}
func send(url: String) -> String {
 //        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        print("Error! Invalid URL!") //Do something else
 //            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        return ""
    }
    print("send URL: \(url)")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    var data: Data? = nil

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, _, _) -> Void in
        data = responseData

        print("send URL session data: \(String(describing: data))")
        let parser = XMLParser(data: data!)
        parser.delegate = self as? XMLParserDelegate
        if parser.parse() {
            print(self.results ?? "No results")
        }
        semaphore.signal()

        }.resume()

 //        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)

    let reply = data.flatMap { String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8) } ?? ""
    return reply
}

public func getSearchItem(searchKeyword: String) -> [String:AnyObject]{

    let timestampFormatter: DateFormatter
    timestampFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timestampFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
    timestampFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    timestampFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

//        let responsegroupitem: String = "ItemAttributes"
//        let responsegroupImages:String = "Images"

//        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    let operationParams: [String: String] = [
        "Service": "AWSECommerceService",
        "Operation": "ItemSearch",
        "ResponseGroup": "Images,ItemAttributes",
        "IdType": "ASIN",
        "SearchIndex":"All",
        "Keywords": searchKeyword,
        "AWSAccessKeyId": urlEncode(CameraViewController.kAmazonAccessID),
        "AssociateTag": urlEncode(CameraViewController.kAmazonAssociateTag),
        "Timestamp": urlEncode(timestampFormatter.string(from: Date()))]

    let signedParams = signedParametersForParameters(parameters: operationParams)



    let query = signedParams.map { "\($0)=\($1)" }.joined(separator: "&")
    let url = "http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?" + query
    print("querydata::::\(query)")

    let reply = send(url: url)
    print("reply::::\(reply)")
 //        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()



    return [:]
}
```

Created bridging header file #import .

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

  getSearchItem(searchKeyword: searchKeyword)

}
```

Here is my console output:[image]

My issue is when tapping search button product searched was not listing. What mistake done i don't know. Can anyone help me out of this pls..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Query_QueryAuth.html):

> The HTTPRequestURI component is the HTTP absolute path component of the URI up to, but not including, the query string. If the HTTPRequestURI is empty, use a forward slash ( / ).
>
> HTTPRequestURI is always "/onca/xml" for Product Advertising API. HTTPVerb is either GET or POST.

Try just setting requestURL to "/onca/xml" instead of the full URL you shouldn't be sending the full URL or the query string in this part.

Also you need to percent encode the values that you are sending. You are sending commas in the response group property which should be percent encoded

```
let operationParams: [String: String] = [
    "Service": "AWSECommerceService",
    "Operation": "ItemSearch",
    "ResponseGroup": urlEncode("Images,ItemAttributes"),
    "IdType": "ASIN",
    "SearchIndex":"All",
    "Keywords": urlEncode(searchKeyword),
    "AWSAccessKeyId": urlEncode(CameraViewController.kAmazonAccessID),
    "AssociateTag": urlEncode(CameraViewController.kAmazonAssociateTag),
    "Timestamp": urlEncode(timestampFormatter.string(from: Date()))]
```

---

```
let stringToSign = "GET\n/onca/xml\n\(query)"
```

Note: You should be using https instead of http

Comment: Thanks for answering!! No actually data is coming when     "ResponseGroup": "Images", value is only images mean will get data from amazon or either if     "ResponseGroup": "Images,ItemAttributes,Offers", value like images, offers mean signature are failed.

Comment: Extremely sorry. i have update my question  and console output image too

Comment: I have updated the answer with some different suggestions. please remove comments related to previous version of answer.

Comment: can have sample of it

Comment: Updated answer again

Comment: Hi. I couldn't get this to work. The signature does not match is returned every time. Do i need to sort the parameters before adding to url?