# SignatureDoesNotMatch After Multiple Code Verifications

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-product-api

I have gone over [Amazon's documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html) many times, but I’m constantly getting SignatureDoesNotMatch errors and am not sure where I’m having the challenge.

[My code](https://gist.github.com/claytonzaugg/55fcb7494a88c8251c32483c61fdc4c9)

Error message from the console log:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Any help pointing me in the right direction, or advising me where I may have fallen short on syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the **exact** solution I was looking for

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587599/how-to-properly-sign-a-get-request-to-amazons-itemlookup-using-client-side-java)